# Nginx with gunicorn with double authorization

Tags: python, nginx, gunicorn

I want to use http auth but also, a reverse proxy using gunicorn.

For http auth I use:

```
location = admin.html {
 auth_basic 'Login Required'
 auth_basic__use_file etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}
```

for gunicorn, proxy reverse I found:

```
try_files $uri @gunicorn;
```

How can I combine both ?

Comment: You want to reverse proxy it to where and on what conditions?

Comment: behind is django and there is a gunicorn socket in the settings; you can use any directory path(i want just to see how can be done)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you mean you want to use nginx as a reverse proxy server for django with additional level of authorization? You simply move your `auth_basic` and `auth_basic_user_file` directives from `location` block to `server` block:

```
upstream gunicorn_server {
    server unix:</path/to/socket/pseudo/file>;
}

server {
    listen ...;
    server_name ...;
    auth_basic "Login Required";
    auth_basic_user_file etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    ... # other parameters
    location / {
        try_files $uri @gunicorn;
    }
    location @gunicorn {
        proxy_pass http://gunicorn_server;
    }
}
```

**Update**

Assuming there is an "admin" area which includes both `/admin.html` and `/admin/any/other/uri` to additionaly protect this area with HTTP Basic Auth you can use following configuration:

```
upstream gunicorn_server {
    server unix:</path/to/socket/pseudo/file>;
}

server {
    listen ...;
    server_name ...;
    ... # other parameters
    location / {
        try_files $uri @gunicorn;
    }
    location /admin {
        auth_basic "Login Required";
        auth_basic_user_file etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        try_files $uri @gunicorn;
    }
    location @gunicorn {
        proxy_pass http://gunicorn_server;
    }
}
```

To protect a single file `admin.html` replace `location /admin {` with `location = /admin.html {`.

Comment: yes, but if you look at my code I want just for specific uri, in the example admin.html; so everything is served as reverse proxy by gunicorn, but in the case of admin I want to ask about password also at the level of nginx; so I need to be in location, because is not for everything

Comment: Is `admin.html` just a static file, or this request must also be passed to gunicorn?